# gnuplot empty y range / plotting data at 0

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have a series of important data that show some measure at 0; how can I plot those data with gnuplot, see those measures as a line, and without receiving the following error: `Warning: empty y range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]`.

Here's a MWE:

```
plot '-'
input> 1 0
input> 2 0
input> 3 0
input> e
```

Here is what I see:

[image]

I was expecting a line with three data points, from 1,0 to 3,0. How can I make that?

Comment: Your other two points are hidden by the vertical plot borders.  If you want the horizontal range to extend beyond that of the input x coordinates you can either set an explicit range (set xrange [0:4]) or request extra whitespace separating the data points from the plot borders (set offsets 1,1,1,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ethan Merritt has mentioned in his comment, you should / need to set the plot range explicitly. My preferred way is to include it in the plot instruction:

```
plot[0:4][-.5:+.5] '-'
```

would be a good fit for your sample data. Other ways of setting the range are possible, as Ethan says.

In order to get a line rather than points, you again need to instruct gnuplot, simply telling it `with lines`, or if you prefer a shorthand, `w l`:

```
plot[0:4][-.5:+.5] '-' w l
```

gives you, for your sample data:

[image]

Comment: It didn't even occur to me that my data was there, I just wasn't looking at it right. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: how come you prefer to put the plot axis with the plot instructions rather than with `set yrange [0:1]`?

Comment: Just a matter of taste. When you set it with `set yrange` it is valid throughout your session - may make life easier but also more confusing if you do different graphs with different ranges at the same time. Doing it with the plot instruction is more typing but you always know what you get.

Comment: How do I suppress the gnuplot warning ? I am generating many plots with a script with different y-axis, and want the gnuplot autoscaling feature which would be disabled if I use `set yrange`.